# manipulating (nested) JSON keys and there values, using nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I am currently facing an issue where I have to read a JSON file that has mostly the same structure, has about 10k+ lines, and is nested.

I thought about creating my own custom processor which reads the JSON and replaces several matching key/values to the ones needed. As I am trying to use NiFi I assume that there should be a more comfortable way as the JSON-structure itself is mostly consistent.

I already tried using the `ReplaceText` processor as well as the `JoltTransformJson` processor, but I could not figure out. How can I transform both keys and values, if needed? For example: if there is something like this:

```
{
    "id": "test"
},
{
    "id": "14"
}
```

It might be necessary to turn the "id" into "Number" and map "test" to "3", as I am using different keys/values in my jsonfiles/database, so they need to fit those. Is there a way of doing so without having to create my own processor?

Regards,
Steve

Comment: it's not clear why `"test"` should be mapped to `"3"`. please edit your question and provide larger input and output examples.

Comment: The keys and values I am receiving differ from those, that I am using (for my json/db later on). So for example the json-file uses as key "name" while I am using "companyname" or the value "DE" needs to be mapped to "276" (as of ISO 3166). It is pretty hard to be more accurate about this, but I hope you are getting my point.